# How do I extract information from a p tag?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about arrays right now and I was just using some new methods I learned about so I can see if I understand their purpose and way of executing well enough. Specifically, I am working with reverse and sort methods. I wanted for their effects to stack on each other, so I wrote this code:

```html
<p id="pstuff"></p>

<button onclick="alphabe();">Alphabetize</button>

<button onclick="rever();">Reverse</button>

<script>
    var listita =  ["Plant", "Seed", "Tree", "Soil"];

    var pInformation = document.getElementById("pstuff");

    function alphabe(){

        document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = pInformation.sort();
    }
    function rever(){
    
        document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = pInformation.reverse();
    }
    document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita ;
</script>
```

It didn't work and I think it is because of the variable pInformation. I'm pretty sure that's not how you extract the information in a p tag, and I want to know how. If the issue isn't pInformation, please do tell. I also want to say that I'm a beginner so I would really appreciate the simplest answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the innerHTML you are retrieving isn't an array anymore; once placed into an element it becomes a string of text. If you apply the array methods to the actual array, your code will work.

```html
<p id="pstuff"></p>

<button onclick="alphabe();">Alphabetize</button>

<button onclick="rever();">Reverse</button>

<script>
    var listita =  ["Plant", "Seed", "Tree", "Soil"];

    var pInformation = document.getElementById("pstuff");

    function alphabe(){

        document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita.sort();
    }
    function rever(){
    
        document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita.reverse();
    }
    document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita ;
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't give him a snippet voluntarily cause he's a beginner. He needs to make his brain work a little to understand his error in this case and not repeat it in a near future. You're not really helping by giving him a "pre-made-copy-paste-it-works" answer. But that's nice of you though

Comment: So what this means is if I do a modification to the array inside a p tag it modifies the whole array? Because if that is not the case then I think I'm missing something

Comment: The array isn't being changed from within the p tag; its being changed by calling .sort on it. The p tag text is then replaced entirely with the modified array.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = pInformation.sort();` with `document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita.sort();`

Comment: To expand on/explain this answer, it's because  `document.getElementById("pstuff")` returns the `p` element just like you think it does, but you can't sort or reverse a single `p` tag -- that doesn't make any sense. What @r0ultio's change does is sort or reverse the items in `listita`, then put that information in the inner HTML of your `p` tag.

Comment: Thanks mate I was just coming back to explain a little bit more ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take the reverse function:

```
function rever(){
    var pInformation = document.getElementById("pstuff").innerText.split(',');
    document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = pInformation.reverse().join(',');
}
```

Use innerText to get the p text, then convert to an array before reversing. See if you can follow the same pattern for sort ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you're trying to do is use the `reverse()` and `sort()` array methods on your `listita` array. It doesn't work on `pInformation` because that is a DOM node accessed using `document.getElementById()`, not an array. Probably just a typo in your code I would guess.

```html
<p id="pstuff"></p>

<button onclick="alphabe()">Alphabetize</button>

<button onclick="rever()">Reverse</button>

<script>
    var listita =  ["Plant", "Seed", "Tree", "Soil"];

    var pInformation = document.getElementById("pstuff");

    function alphabe(){
        document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita.sort();
    }
    function rever(){
        document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita.reverse();
    }
    document.getElementById("pstuff").innerHTML = listita ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Array.join(' ')` and `String.split(' ')` to convert the array into a space-separated string (and back) as needed.

```html
<p id="pstuff"></p>

<button onclick="alphabet();">Alphabetize</button>
<button onclick="reverse();">Reverse</button>

<script>
  var pInfo = document.getElementById("pstuff");
  
  const write = (arr) => pInfo.textContent = arr.join(' ');
  const read = () => pInfo.textContent.split(' ');
  
  var myList = ["Plant", "Seed", "Tree", "Soil"];
  
  const alphabet = () => write(read().sort());
  const reverse = () => write(read().reverse());
  
  write(myList);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The

tags are created by the following js code:

```
paragraph = document.createElement("p");
text = document.createTextNode("first");
paragraph.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(paragraph);
```

Therefore, you should have the means for javascript to remember the contents of these paragraphs without needing to retreive them from the DOM.

Create a javascript array

`````
Now instead of document.getElementById(....) you can just do txt = paraContents['mydiv_n']```` .

It's horribly inefficient because there are two copies of each set of para text, but it's paractical if you can't get Chrome to play ball with getElementById. Depending on exactly what problem Chrome is having, you may be able to get away with storing references to the paras, rather than their contents. This will be much more efficient.`enter code here`
`````